# What version of Red Hat Enterprise will work with .NET Core?

Tags: .net, linux, redhat

I have been researching .NET Core and Red Hat Linux compatibility and from my very limited and basic understanding, it seems like it will only work with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2. Can anyone shed some light on whether this is true? Or perhaps I am not understanding how it all works, this being my first real encounter with both .NET and Linux! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with any RHEL 7.x
Red Hat is preparing a very user-friendly release (via Software Collections), this should be released soon.

In the meanwhile check out Don Schenck's blog articles at redhat.developers.com.  Don's all about .NET on RHEL.

http://developers.redhat.com/blog/author/donschenck/